# How to bind column in datagridview to an array element in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2015.
I have a winform with a datagridview.
I have a custom class

```
   public class deNode
   {
     public byte machine {get;set;}
     public DateTime eDate {get;set;}
     public int[] errorCode {get;set;}
   }
```

I have :

```
List<deNode> equipment;
```

I want to use equipment as `DataSource` for the `DataGridView` and specify `errorCode[0],errorCode[1]..errorCode[17]` as `DataPropertyName`s for individual columns in the DataGridView.

I have tried `equipmentGrid.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "errorCode[2]"` but that doesn't work.  How can I achieve my goal?

appreciate any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to… “flatted” the `errorCode` array. The grid will not do this for you automatically. If the number of elements is fixed, the class could create individual properties for each element in the array. Or create a single property to “concatenate” all the values in `errorcode` into a single string. A better approach would be to use two (2) grids in a Master-detail scenario.

Comment: Can you give an example of "class could create individual properties for each element in the array"  ?  Or point to an example.  It would help clarify for me.

Comment: Are the number of elements in the `errorCode` array "FIXED"? In other words if there are 17 elements in the array, then, are there ALWAYS 17 elements, no more and no less?

Comment: yes it is fixed

Comment: Add 17 properties to the `deNode` class... something like...   `public int errCode0 => errorCode[0];` `public int errCode1 => errorCode[1];` ... etc...

Answer (score 0):

Separate your model from the way you display your model. Make something similar to a `VideModel`, an adapter between the model and the DataGridView.

Apart from that this solves your problem, it will also make it possible to change your HMI without having to change your model. In future you can (within limits) change your model, without having to change the datagridview.

```
class ViewModelDeNode
{
    public DeNode DeNode {get; set;}

    public int ErrorCode00 => this.DeNode.ErrorCode[00];
    public int ErrorCode01 => this.DeNode.ErrorCode[01];
    ...
}
```

The columns in your DataGridView:

```
DataGridViewColumn columnErrorCode01 = new DataGridViewColumn()
{
    Name = ...
    HeaderText = "Error code 01",
    DataPropertyName = nameof(ViewModelDenode.ErrorCode01),
    ...
};


IEnumerable<DeNode> deNodes = ...
IEnumerable<ViewModelDenode> displayableDeNodes = deNodes
    .Select(deNode => new ViewModelDeNode
    {
        DeNode = deNode,
    });

DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView(...);
dgv.DataSource = displayableDeNodes.ToList();
```

Or if you want to edit the datagridview (add / remove / update rows):

```
dgv.DataSource = new BindingList<ViewModelDeNode>(displayableDeNodes);
```